# What is a thermal source and its spectral-thermal modes?

Tags: photons, atomic-physics, thermal-radiation

I know what a thermal state is. But I am wondering how we can determine that a source is thermal or not? E.g. is the light coming out from an LED, thermal?

On the other hand, what are spectral-thermal modes of a thermal source? How we can specify or measure them?

Can anyone point me to a resource in these topics for further reading?

Comment: Can you provide a source where you have the term "spectral-thermal mode" from?